# How do I test a watcher on a tool that was imported in my component?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I use an instance of a class as a tool in one of my components. This component watches for changes in the class instance. However I fail at writing a test for that watcher.

I tried using `jest.fn`, `spyOn` and a `setData`, but none of these worked.

The class looks like this:

```
export default class myTool {
    constructor () {
        this._myData = null
    }

    get myData () {
        return this._myData
    }

    set myData (updatedMyData) {
        this._myData = updatedMyData
    }
}
```

And the component:

```
import myTool from '@/utils/myTool'
export default {
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            myTool: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleMyDataUpdate(updatedMyData) {
            // do something
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$watch('myTool.myData', (updatedMyData) => {
            this.handleMyDataUpdate(updatedMyData)
        })
        this.myTool = new myTool()
    }
    ...
}
```

#### 1st attempt with `jest.fn`:

test:

```
it('should call handleMyDataUpdate on myData update.', () => {
    const wrapper = mountComponent()
    const handleMyDataUpdate = jest.fn()
    wrapper.setMethods({ handleMyDataUpdate })
    wrapper.vm.myTool.myData = 5
    expect(handleMyDataUpdate).toBeCalled()
})
```

### 2nd attempt with `spyOn`:

test:

```
it('should call handleMyDataUpdate on myData update.', () => {
    const wrapper = mountComponent()
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handleMyDataUpdate')
    wrapper.vm.myTool.myData = 5
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
}
```

### 3rd attempt with `setData`:

test:

```
it('should call handleMyDataUpdate on myData update.', () => {
    const wrapper = mountComponent()
    const handleMyDataUpdate = jest.fn()
    wrapper.setMethods({ handleMyDataUpdate })
    wrapper.setData({
        myTool: {
            myData: 5
        }
    })
    expect(handleMyDataUpdate).toBeCalled()
}
```

---

**Result:** the 3 things I tried always fail with the following reason: `Expected mock function to have been called.`, whether I comment the line where `myData` is updated or not.

### Other things that I tried:

I tried wrapping the `expect` line within a `$nextTick`, but it doesn't work either:

```
wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
    // expectation
    done()
})
```

The following error outputs and the test is always considered as "passed", whereas it should be "failed":

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:1739
{ Error: expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
```

Looking at line 1739 of `vue.runtime.common.js` didn't help.

So how do I do to test my watcher?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `_myData` in the `myTool` class is initially `undefined`, so it's not reactive. To resolve the issue, initialize `_myData` in `myTool`'s constructor:

```
class myTool {
  constructor() {
    this._myData = null
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then, your "1st attempt" test should pass successfully.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3nvy0v6n3?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.spec.js&previewwindow=tests)

Comment: Well this was an interesting answer but I actually do assign a value to `_myData` in my real code. The example I gave is a bit too much simplified in that way. I will add this assignation in the question.

Comment: Hmm. Can you edit the codesandbox to match your exact use case? That would help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Here's a sample closer to the real code: https://codesandbox.io/s/knk5xn8l3

Comment: I managed to make it work! In my original code I instantiated a myTool after setting the watcher, unlike your codepen... And unlike the original question code (shame on me). Yet it was reactive since I could log things in the watcher function and see the result in the console... Not sure what's happening... But it seems like my tests are working properly now.

Comment: I need the tool instance to be created AFTER the watcher, since the watcher should look at changes made in the constructor. If I instanciate the tool BEFORE the watcher, the whole set of instructions contained in the constructor will be executed before the watcher is set. As a result, the watcher callback won't be called. My conclusion of that is that either Jest and Vue-test-utils are not strong enough to be useful in my case, OR it is my code that is badly designed.

Comment: In this codesandbox, both the vue when loaded in the browser and the test show the correct output in the console, yet the test fails because the watcher has "not been called" (it actually has). It seems like it is merely the test which is badly written. It doesn't seem to be a problem to instanciate a watcher before instanciating the data structure that is being watched: codesandbox.io/s/ppv1pnwoyj